# Conditional column function if one of the features is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a Dataframe which shows measurements of an item, such as Length, Width and Height:

```
Length  Width   Height  Operator
102.67  49.53   19.69   Op-1
102.50  51.42   19.63   Op-1
95.37   52.25   21.51   Op-1
94.77   49.24   18.60   Op-1
104.26  47.90   19.46   Op-1
```

Analyzing the `boxplot_stats` from matplolib, I'm trying to create a column named "Status" where, if any of the measures (at least one of them) are above of `whishi` or below the `whislo` it will be consider as 'Defective'.

So I've tried many possibilities, but none of them worked as expected:

```
feat = ['Length','Width','Height']
    
for item, feat in df:
    if df[feat].iloc[item] > boxplot_stats(df[feat])[0]['whishi'] | df[feat].iloc[item] < boxplot_stats(df[feat])[0]['whislo']:
        df['Status'] = 'Defective'
    else:
        df['Status'] = 'Perfect'
```

Another one:

```
def status(row):
    feat = ['Length','Width','Height']
    for feature in feat:
        if df.iloc[row][feat] > boxplot_stats(df[feat])[0]['whishi'] | df.iloc[row][feat] < boxplot_stats(df[feat])[0]['whislo']:
            val = 'Defective'
        else:
            val = 'Perfect'
        return val

df['status'] = df.apply(status, axis=1)
```

For instance, the `boxplot_stats` is obtained like:

```
In:
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats
boxplot_stats(df['Height'])

Out:
[{'mean': 20.29322,
  'iqr': 1.6674999999999969,
  'cilo': 20.192920598732098,
  'cihi': 20.4270794012679,
  'whishi': 23.39,
  'whislo': 17.37,
  'fliers': array([], dtype=float64),
  'q1': 19.475,
  'med': 20.31,
  'q3': 21.1425}]
```

In that way, I access the `whishi` like:

```
In:
boxplot_stats(df['Height'])[0]['whishi']

Out:
23.39
```

The expected result is a column of strings with values 'Defective' or 'Perfect', which I'll later treat as 0 or 1.

Comment: could you please also share the boxplot_stats data?

Comment: @Rabinzel for sure, now I shared the boxplot_stats data

Comment: just to get that right. you basically want to check in each row the 3 values (length, height, width) whether each of them is bigger than whishi or smaller than wishlo, right ? and if only one of them 3 meet the condition, it gets the result `defective`, if all 3 fail `Perfect`?

Comment: @Rabinzel Yes, I want to check the 3 values in each row, each one considering the `whishi` and `whislo` of each measure. So if any of the measures is consider `defective`, the `status` must be consider `defective` regardless the other measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up some things there. I try to explain my solution the best I can, maybe you figure out where you went wrong.

```
def get_status(row):
    # when applying the function get_status(), it is called each row at a time
    # row is a pd.Series
    #print('row: ', row, '\n') <- try if you want to see what gets passed to the function
    for col in ['Length','Width','Height']:
        # in each row you have to check 3 values (3 columns)
        # if this if condition is True only once, the function returns 'Defective'
        if (
            (row[col] > boxplot_stats(df[col])[0]['whishi']) 
            or 
            (row[col] < boxplot_stats(df[col])[0]['whislo'])
        ):
            
            return 'Defective'
        
    # if it didn't return anything till here (-> 3x condition was False) it will return `Perfect
    return 'Perfect'

df['Status'] = df.apply(get_status,axis=1)
print(df)

   Length  Width  Height Operator     Status
0  102.67  49.53   19.69     Op-1    Perfect
1  102.50  51.42   19.63     Op-1    Perfect
2   95.37  52.25   21.51     Op-1  Defective
3   94.77  49.24   18.60     Op-1  Defective
4  104.26  47.90   19.46     Op-1    Perfect
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I compared it to my own code and now I can see where I was thinking wrong. =)